# 'pandas' has no attribute 'tslib'

Tags: python, pandas

```
df['tick'] = np.where(df.Length < .05, df.index, pd.tslib.NaT)
```

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'tslib'
when I run this one it shows me that pandas tslib is not found how can I resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just use `pd.NaT`:

```
df['tick'] = np.where(df.Length < .05, df.index, pd.NaT)
```

As mentioned in [this](https://github.com/yhat/ggpy/issues/617) GitHub thread:

> `FutureWarning: pandas.tslib is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.`

So it is remove now and it's inaccessible.